# Cannot uniquely identify layout when adding nested fragments with fragmenttransaction

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I am trying to do the following:

1. In activity, **replace** the container with a fragment (TestFragment)
2. This fragment's layout contains a container which is **replaced** by another fragment (TestSubFragment)
3. Clicking on the TestSubFragment makes the activity **add** a new TestFragment over the root container

TestActivity.kt

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TestSubFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

override fun onFragmentInteraction(id: Int) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, TestFragment.newInstance(id)).addToBackStack(null).commit()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, TestFragment.newInstance(1)).addToBackStack(null).commit()
}
}
```

TestFragment.kt

```
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

private var id: Int? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val v = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
    activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.sub_fragment_container, TestSubFragment.newInstance(id!!)).commit()
    return v
}
companion object {
    fun newInstance(id: Int): TestFragment {
        val fragment = TestFragment()
        fragment.id = id
        return fragment
    }
}
}
```

TestSubFragment.kt

```
class TestSubFragment : Fragment() {

private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null
private var id: Int? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val v = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_test, container, false)
    v.id_text.text = id.toString()
    v.id_text.setOnClickListener { _ -> mListener?.onFragmentInteraction(v.id_text.text.toString().toInt() + 1) }
    return v
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = context
    }
}

interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    fun onFragmentInteraction(id: Int)
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(id: Int): TestSubFragment {
        val fragment = TestSubFragment()
        fragment.id = id
        return fragment
    }
}
}
```

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ckl.happens.TestActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_test.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="ckl.happens.TestFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_sub_test.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="ckl.happens.TestFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Problem is that the replace fragment line in TestFragment.kt is finding the first R.id.sub_fragment_container from the xml hierarchy so it is replacing the incorrect container instead of the last/new container.

I tried adding tag in fragmenttransaction or change R.id.sub_fragment_container to v.sub_fragment_container.id but no luck.

I don't want to change add() to replace() in onFragmentInteraction because the fragment will be recreated and I want to keep everything in the fragment unchanged when the user back to that fragment.

I can't find detailed article on nesting fragments for my case.

I am working with Kotlin but I can also understand Java. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem without getting the new container id.

I decided to remove fragmenttransaction and add the fragment in the xml. Then in the fragment (parent fragment) that contains the sub-fragment, get the sub-fragment with `childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment)`. Finally update the content of the sub-fragment from the parent fragment.

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)

        val fragment1 = TestFragment.newInstance(1)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment1).commit()

        val fragment2 = TestFragment.newInstance(2)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment2).addToBackStack(null).commit()

        val fragment3 = TestFragment.newInstance(3)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment3).addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }
}

class TestFragment : Fragment() {
    private var id: Int? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false)
        val subFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment) as TestSubFragment
        subFragment.view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.id_text)?.text = id.toString()
        return v
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(id: Int): TestFragment {
            val fragment = TestFragment()
            fragment.id = id
            return fragment
        }
    }
}

class TestSubFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sub_test, container, false)
    }
}
```

activity_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ckl.happens.TestActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_test.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="ckl.happens.TestFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="ckl.happens.TestSubFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_sub_test.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="ckl.happens.TestFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="" />

</FrameLayout>
```